# What is the best IDE when using knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm looking to start using knockout.  What is the best IDE when using knockout.js? Most of the literature mentions VS2010, is there a good free alternative?

Comment: interesting question, closed as usual as non constructive by the genial SO moderators...congratulations

Comment: From what I know, anything related to preferences about tools is closed on SO. There should be a section for IDE and tools somewhere on Stack Exchange, though. Because sometime, it just takes several months before you realize you're not using the good tools.

Comment: Cannot answer, so I left a comment. [Starting from Netbeans 7.4](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_74_NewAndNoteworthy#Knockout), there is some basic knockout support. Check [some screencasts](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-knockout-screencast.html) too.

Answer (score 3):

I love [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) , it's multi-platform, super-easy and very configurable.
It's not free per se, but they let you try it out with no limitation for whatever time you want. The licenses are very cheap and you don't have to buy one for each O.S.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use something simple like notepad++ for javascript. If you want something more then Eclipse offers a javascript version.

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud 9 IDE](http://c9.io/). I won't say it's the **best**, but it's a good option.

> Cloud9 is a state-of-the-art IDE that runs in your browser and lives
>   in the cloud, allowing you to run, debug and deploy applications from
>   anywhere, anytime. A complete game-changer that will change the way we
>   develop applications forever.